# Espaçamento entre linhas TextArea

Tags: html, css

Tenho um duvida na qual ja estou a batalhar a algum tempo, queria adicionar mais espaçamento entre linhas da textarea .

Aqui encontra-se uma imagem atual da minha text area que quero adiconar espaçamento entre linhas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.notes {
 width: 77%;
 background-attachment: local;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px), repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 31px, black 31px, black 33px, black 32px);
 line-height: 31px;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 border: none;
 margin-left: -9px;
      margin-right: 0px;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" class="notes" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" ></textarea>
<label style="position: absolute; margin-top: -10px; margin-left: -20px;" class="valign-top">Mensagem</label>
```

Comment: Não basta alterar o `line-height` e os valores em `background-image`? Você definiu os valores para deixar o espaçamento atual, então basta adaptá-los para o que deseja. Não entendi qual é o intuito da pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funciona assim o `line-height` tem que bater com o maior valor do gradiente que faz as linhas. Veja as duas imagens abaixo para entender melhor. Ajuste os valores e vc pode colocar a linha do tamanho que quiser.

Veja esse código: Repare nos valores em negrito

`repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 41px, black 41px, black 43px);
 line-height: 43px;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código com o entre linhas aumentado

```css
.notes {
    width: 77%;
    background-attachment: local;
    
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px),
                        repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 41px, black 41px, black 43px);
    line-height: 43px;

    padding: 8px 10px;
    border: none;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" class="notes" id="mensagem" name="mensagem"></textarea>

<label style="position: absolute; margin-top: -10px; margin-left: -20px;" class="valign-top">Mensagem</label>
```

Comment: valeuu, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Roberto sem problemas meu caro, que bom que funcionou ai!